# Export/Import Glabal term store

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, csom, pnp-powershell

We are migrating Global term store from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Online. Can i get the scripts to export term store from SharePoint 2013 in a text file and then import that in SharePoint Online? We want to upload/download using CSOM script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell command to export the term store in SharePoint 2013 into CSV file, and then import to SharePont Online.

More information and PowerShell command check the article:

[PowerShell for SharePoint 2013: Export TermSet to CSV](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/PowerShell-for-SharePoint-a838b5d0)

[Migrate SharePoint 2010 Term Store to SharePoint Online with PowerShell](https://www.sptrenches.com/2016/08/migrate-term-store-to-sharepoint-online.html)